# How to access a property which is a class using Expressions

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I have a class called "User" which has a property defined as a class "Department" (i also want to know what is it called, LOL). I want to access the property in the "Department" class called "Name" (User.Department.Name). It throws a NulLReferenceException when I input the arguement into the compiled expression.

I have this code below. Thanks in advance.

```
        ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "user");
        MemberExpression depPropExpr = MemberExpression.Property(paramExpr, "Department");
        MemberExpression depNamePropExpr = MemberExpression.Property(depPropExpr, "Name");
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant("SBCA");

        var expression = Expression.Assign(depNamePropExpr, constantExpression); var compiledExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<User>>(expression, new[] { paramExpr }).Compile();
        compiledExpression(user);
```

Comment: What doesn't work with your code?

Comment: Write the code as if you would do it without an expression. Then build the expression-tree.

Comment: It throws a NullReferenceException when i compile it. var compiledExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<User>>(expression, new[] { paramExpr }).Compile();
            compiledExpression(user);

Comment: How are you compiling it? How are you using it? [Edit] your question and include all relevant pieces

Comment: Thanks, i'll dig into it.

Comment: Oh, it just happened that I didn't instantiated my Department property. One more thing :D, may I know what is it called? The property which is a class. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kL4AqA) your code works fine.

```
public class Program
{

    public static void Main()
    {
        var user = new User();
        user.Department = new Department();
        user.Department.Name = "hello";
        Console.WriteLine("Before: " + user.Department.Name);

        ParameterExpression paramExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(User), "user");
        MemberExpression depPropExpr = MemberExpression.Property(paramExpr, "Department");
        MemberExpression depNamePropExpr = MemberExpression.Property(depPropExpr, "Name");
        ConstantExpression constantExpression = Expression.Constant("SBCA");

        var expression = Expression.Assign(depNamePropExpr, constantExpression);

        var compiledExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<User>>(expression, new[] { paramExpr }).Compile();
        compiledExpression(user);
        Console.WriteLine("After: " + user.Department.Name);
    }
}

public class User
{
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Output:

> Before: hello
>   After: SBCA

The problem (the `NullReferenceException`) is that `user.Department` is `null`, where your expression is doing `user.Department.Name = "SBCA";`.
You can test this by removing the assignment of `user.Department = new...`

Comment: Thanks again sir.